# Embarassingly simple OpenMP parallelization is slower on multiple threads

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, simulation, montecarlo

I'm encountering a strange problem when trying to parallelize a Monte Carlo simulation. I've got a simulator that's simulating the dynamics of circumplanetary dust particles. I've basically set up a simple Monte Carlo simulation, executing thousands of dust particle simulations that are all independent, and only different because of a different initial state.

The for-loop that runs the Monte Carlo simulation seems to work fine when I execute it on a single thread, and call one of the [odeint](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2) integrate functions inside the body of the for-loop using any of one of the steppers available.

As soon as I parallelize the for-loop over multiple threads, a really peculiar thing happens: the whole Monte Carlo simulation suddenly takes MUCH longer to execute. For instance, when I'm running 10 dust particle simulations, each for 1000 years, using the Bulirsch-Stoer dense output stepper, it takes 15 mins on 1 thread and 1hr 15 mins on 2 threads!

It makes absolutely no sense and I've been going through the code line-by-line to understand what's causing this. I'm totally stumped and now I'm starting to wonder whether for some reason `OpenMP` is misbehaving under the hood. There are no race conditions from what I can see and any shared data is `const`.

My simulator codebase can be found here: https://github.com/kartikkumar/dustsim

The problem relates to this line in my bulk particle simulator: https://github.com/kartikkumar/dustsim/blob/master/src/bulkParticleSimulator.cpp#L342

I'm running the simulations on a server with the following config:

- 64x AMD Opteron(TM) Processor 6276
- 256 GB RAM
- openSUSE 12.1
- gcc 6.1.0
- cmake 3.9.4
- boost 1.65.1

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
const int numberOfThreads = 2;
const int numberOfParticles = 10;
const Dynamics dynamics( parameters, ... );

const double startEpoch = 0.0;
const double stepSize = 3600.0 * 24.0 * 365.25;
const int outputSteps = 1000;

typedef std::map< Int, State > InitialStates;
InitialStates initialStates;

for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; ++i )
{
    // Generate random initial state (size: 6) using Boost generators and push them into map.
    State state = f( randomGenerator, parameters, ... );

    // Key is set to a unique simulation ID.
    initialStates[ simulationId ] = state;
}

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads( numberOfThreads )
    for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < initialStates.size( ); ++j )
    {
        InitialStates::iterator initialState = initialStates.begin( );
        std::advance( initialState, j );

        const int simulationId = initialState->first;
        const State currentState = initialState->second;

#pragma omp critical( outputToConsole )
        {
            std::cout << "Executing simulation ID: " << simulationId << std::endl;
        }

        // Convert state using a conversion function.
        State convertedState = f( currentState, parameters, ... );

        std::ostringstream integrationOutput;
        const StateHistoryWriter writer( integrationOutput, parameters, ... );

        using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
        bulirsch_stoer_dense_out< State > stepper( absoluteTolerance, relativeTolerance );
        integrate_n_steps( stepper,
                           dynamics,
                           convertedState,
                           startEpoch,
                           stepSize,
                           outputSteps,
                           writer );

        // Write output generated by numerical integrator to SQLite database.
        // To avoid locking of the database, this section is thread-critical, so will be
        // executed one-by-one by multiple threads.
#pragma omp critical( writeOutputToDatabase )
           {
           }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you serious to think the Community Members will read through thousands of SLOCs just to find an improperly formulated problem and solve it? **Better re-read how to ask the MCVE-formulated problems** and update your post with an indeed **M**inimum **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample of code, that reconstructs in-vitro the problem, that you have already tried to solve, post what tests + approaches you have tried so far and what observations were made before you decided to ask the Community, ok? Last, but not least, this is **not** a Rent-A-Team-of-Experts-For-Free... website. Go MCVE-way

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Bit strange that you would assume that I am demanding Rent-A-Team-of-Experts-For-Free. The MCVE version works fine. Hence, why I pointed to the specific line number where it's failing in the full code implementation. I don't expect anyone to debug my code. Rather, if it turns out that someone has encountered this phenomenon with OpenMP previously, it's possible that there's something I'm overlooking conceptually.

Comment: There are basically two options 1) you use a parallel performance analysis tool to figure out the issue 2) you reproduce it in a [mcve].

Comment: I've added a minimal version of the code, but I'm not sure it captures the problem well enough.

Comment: **In case it does not** "*capture the problem well enough*", you had better **revise the MCVE-formulation and do make it "*capture the problem well enough*"** MCVE-code that does not reflect the problem is a pure nonsense. MCVE-code that does not run, is not an MCVE. Pull stop.

Comment: Again you're seemingly missing what I'm saying. The code that is now in the original post is the MVCE code, nothing more, nothing less. My disclaimer is that I don't know if someone reading the post will get enough from that because I don't know where the problem is. So I've now provided the MVCE code and the full implementation. I'm not entirely sure where your aggression is stemming from.

Comment: You need a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem; without that, nobody can reproduce and diagnose what's happening.  It's likely you have a shared random source that's under contention by all the threads, but it's hard to be sure without the MCVE.  (The code you posted is certainly not **complete** or **verifiable**; it doesn't even compile).

Comment: Since you say this is a Monte-Carlo simulation, my first **GUESS** is that you have a serial random number generator, which suppresses all parallelism.